# How to check if column header is clicked in datagridview using SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using `SelectionChanged` event of a `DataGridView`. I have a code that will display the value of a `DataGridView`'s cell to a `TextBox`. However, when I click the column header, this also triggers the code (I assume because of the `SelectionChanged` event) and will display an error.

What I want to achieve is to enclose my codes in the `datagridview1_SelectionChanged` in an `if` statement. Wherein:

```
if(column header is clicked)    
    //don't do anything`    
else    
    //do the display of data to textbox`
```

I just want to know the code for checking if you clicked a header or not.

Comment: Simply test for if (SelectedCells.Count > 0)

Comment: By default, clicking a column header does not raise the SelectionChanged event. By default it just does sorting, and does not change the selection. It may be custom code that selects all cells in a column? what happens when you click your column header. try debugging your stacktrace at this point.

Comment: @TaW, I tried the code. It partially worked because I still get the error but then displays my sample `MessageBox` inside the `SelectedCells.Count > 0`. I debugged it and found out that it still goes to my Exception in `catch` because I think when the `SelectionChanged` triggers, the `SelectedCells.Count` is not 0 and goes to the `catch` then it goes back to the checking of `SelectedCells.Count` and it counts now as 0 and will display the sample `MessageBox`

Comment: @Tewr
Whatever you clicked in datagridview (column or not), if you have SelectionChanged event, it will trigger

Comment: @PhilipSy: It is not standard. Its being trigged by something else.

Comment: @Tewr I think that would be the reordering of rows alphabetically when you clicked the column header. The selected value in first row will change, thus the trigger of SelectionChanged

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check your `DataGridView`'s `CurrentRow` for null. If it is not null it means that you've not clicked the column header:

```
private void yourDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var current = yourDataGridView.CurrentRow;
    if (current != null) // Means that you've not clicked the column header
    {
        //Display the value of a DataGridView's cell to a TextBox    
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it finally solved my problem! :) Thanks a lot S.Akbari! I modified your code a little bit:
`if(dgvSuppliers.CurrentRow == null)`

`{`

`MessageBox.Show("Column header clicked");`

`}`

`else`

`{`

`\\your codes here`

`}`

Answer (score 9):

just check in the event

```
List_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     if(e.Rowindex>-1)
        ...
}
```

-1 is for header